# Select all records of a maximum column from codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, oracle, codeigniter

I am using Oracle11g
What I want to do is to select the field with the max update date.
The code below is selecting the right field in Toad. How do I use this in my php script in CodeIgniter.

```
select * from performance 
where UPDATE_DATE = (select max(UPDATE_DATE) from  performance)
```

**I have this in CodeIgniter but only selecting the UPDATE_DATE column. I also want to select id, shop_name and update_date in the field record**

```
function get_last_insert()
{
$this->db->select_max('UPDATE_DATE');
$query = $this->db->get('PERFORMANCE'); 
echo '<pre>' .$this->db->last_query(). '</pre>';
```

}

Ok. After a lot of research on stackoverflow
The correct answer is

```
function get_last_insert()
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('UPDATE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(UPDATE_DATE) FROM PERFORMANCE)', NULL, FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('WHOUSE1.DLY_BWR_MAN_PERFORMANCE'); 
print_r($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_last_insert()
{
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('UPDATE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(UPDATE_DATE) FROM PERFORMANCE)',     NULL, FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('WHOUSE1.DLY_BWR_MAN_PERFORMANCE'); 
print_r($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function get_last_insert()
{
$this->db->select(' id, shop_name, update_date, MAX(UPDATE_DATE) as UPDATE_DATE', false)->get('PERFORMANCE')->row_array(); 
echo '<pre>' .$this->db->last_query(). '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Nil'z., that's not working.. I got error not a single group-group function

Comment: Can you post your query generated by `$this->db->last_query()`?

Answer (score 0):

This will return the value of $champs_select (a particular field of the max line). and you can also put particular condition in array => $where

```
function getmax_where('performance',$where,'UPDATE_DATE',$champs_select)
{
    $this->db->select_max('UPDATE_DATE');
    $this->db->where($where);
    $maxdate= $this->db->get('performance');

    foreach($maxdate->result() as $row){
        $max= $row->UPDATE_DATE;
    }
    if($max){
    $array=array('UPDATE_DATE'=>$max);

    $array= array_merge($array,$where);

    $this->db->select($champs_select);
    $this->db->where($array);
    $result= $this->db->get('performance');//->result() give all records of a maximum column
    foreach($result->result() as $row){
        $resultat= $row->$champs_select;
    }
    return $resultat;
    }
    return false;
}

?>
```